# Google App Engine - Error when calling back from blob service

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm have developed an application to upload a file to the blobstore. It's working fine on development server, the real server but free version. But, when i tested it on the production server (the paid one), i got the following error when the blob service calls back my API.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from a blob upload callback request.
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.getUploads(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:160)
```

Comment: Can you please share your code where you are creating blob upload URL.

Comment: Ankur, the line produced the error is 

final Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobMap = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().getUploads(request);